# Hyperlink in Email Signarure shows with safelink.protection.outlook.com

Tags: email

I have an issue with Email signature. I added my signature through 
My setting - Email - My email Setting.
When I send email to any one from Salesforce my signature receive like this:

```
    Thanks and best regards

    Russell Baker | Operations Manager
    ——
    Mobile: +1 46 4101910
   MarTrust® | USA | https://emea01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=www.martrust.com&data=01%7c01%7cr.baker%40marcura.com7cc5fa515553c24028a9bb08d3da0a53ac%7cb73af38f601b46c99664281fe920708a7c0&sdata=cSZO9jZqWwmXteMXI2VRiPOrAGuLP65D8Ylc1i6m8%3d
```

I copy and paste my Email signature as plain text but still I am getting long link.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

"Plain text" literally means "plain text." You can't get any pretty formatting in a plain text email. What you send is what the recipient receives. Instead, you need to use HTML format instead.

You need to use HTML tags, as described in [How do I add a link to my email signature?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000003224&language=en_US).

> Go to: Setup | Personal Setup | Email | My Email Settings
>   - Enter the path to the website in the Signature box enclosed in HTML tags as follows
>
> Enter words that display for link
>   here
>
> For example: `<a href="http://login.salesforce.com">Link to Salesforce
>   Login</a>`
>
> Click Save.
>
> **NOTE** If the link does not show, type the coding into the box rather than copying/pasting as sometimes extra characters can get
>   attached with the cut and paste process.   When sending an email from
>   Salesforce, you need to make sure the emails are in HTML format. On
>   the web page to write an email (after buttons "send an email"), locate
>   the section "Email Format". It's at the top of the page, on the right
>   near the "To" field.
>
> - If it says "HTML", you are ok.
> - If it says "Text-Only", you need to click on "Switch to HTML".
>
> If you send an email in "Text-Only" with the modified signature, the
>   logo will not appear, and the signature will include as Enter words that display for link here
>   instead of the highlighted words that click to the website.